# Convert each data frame row to httr body parameter list without enumeration

Tags: r

So, I have a data frame that carries a bunch of values for two form fields. I want to make POST requests per row as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
apply(df, 1, function(x) {
       POST(someURL, accept_json(),
            add_headers('Content-Type' = 'application/json'),
            body = list('x' = x[1], 'y' = x[2]), encode = 'json'))
       })
```

This works fine. However, is there a way to generate `list('x' = x[1], 'y' = x[2])` programmatically without enumerating each value like that since the names of the columns in the data frame are basically the list.

Comment: Just `as.list(x)`? If you're looking to do interesting things with lists, `purrr` is worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on indices, and use `as.list()`:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
lapply(seq_along(df[,1]), function(x) {
       POST(someURL, accept_json(),
            add_headers('Content-Type' = 'application/json'),
            body = as.list(df[x,]), encode = 'json')
})
```